# What is the significance of double square brackets in javascript property names when initializing the object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecma

I'm currently looking at some code that was written a while ago, and I'm not sure why the following 2 statements are equal and for some reason I've chosen to do the first way.

```js
const a = 'foo';
const b = { [[a]]: 'boo' } // This is in code
const c = { [a]: 'boo' } // ES6 way
```

They both seem to produce exactly the same result. I'm not sure if the first option was a valid option pre ES6, but when I tried on node 0.10 for example it didn't recognise either of them as valid statements. It would be helpful to know why double square brackets produce the same result.

Update:

After seeing comments/answer I tried to confirm if the expression within double square brackets is treated as an array, and it is indeed.

```js
> const foo = 'foo'
undefined
> const boo = 'boo'
undefined
> const combo = { [foo,boo]: 'foo boo' }
const combo = { [foo,boo]: 'foo boo' } // This doesn't work foo,boo is not a valid expression 
                    ^

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','
> const combo = { [[foo,boo]]: 'foo boo' }
undefined
> combo
{ 'foo,boo': 'foo boo' } // Treats expression itself as array and `toString()` gets called on the array producing 'foo,boo' string
```

Comment: No idea what that's supposed to be. My IDE is saying it's not valid JS.

Comment: I suspect in the case of `b` you are creating an array with a single element `a` and then trying to use it as an object key through the computed key syntax. Since object keys are strings the array's `toString` method is called which in your case would end up being the string `'foo'`, and that gets used as the computed value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ES6, `[expression]: value` is interpreted as follows:

- evaluate `expression`
- convert the result to a string
- use this string as a key

Respectively,

```
 given [ [a] ]: 'boo'

 evaluate [a]   => ['foo']
 String ['foo'] => 'foo'
 result         => {'foo': 'boo'}
```

In other words, extra brackets are ignored.

Comment: Thanks - is [expression] really treated as a single element array and then run a toString on this array?

Comment: @opensourcegeek: no, the outermost brackets are part of the syntax.  `toString` is applied to what's inside them, e.g. to `expression` not  to`[expression]`